# Covert ZULU time to PST

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql

I am trying to covert start_time which is in yulu format to pst.
Start_time sample: 2020-02-04T04:36:42:211Z

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(sub string(start_time,1,17),'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSZ),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss)
```

But I am getting output as NULL.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP because UNIX_TIMESTAMP returns seconds, you will lose the millisecond component of your timestamp.

```
FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2020-02-04T04:36:42:211Z, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"), 'PST')
```

Sometime it might possible that because of "T" and "Z" our result get distorted.In that case we can use:

```
from_utc_timestamp(CONCAT(substring('2020-02-04T04:36:42:211Z',1,10)," ",substring('2020-02-04T04:36:42:211Z',12,12)),'PST')
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape `T`, `Z` in the string. Note the use of double-quotes for the pattern and `T` and `Z` are escaped with a single-quote.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2020-02-04T04:36:42:211Z',"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS'Z'")
                     ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Also, you don't need a `substring` as you are matching the pattern for the full string.

Comment: Could you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876238/assign-same-value-when-using-lag-function-if-column-used-in-lag-has-same-value